# Silverlight DispatcherTimer make my program not work correctly

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Hi every one i have a phenomenal situation.
My firstly code like this :

```
public MainPage()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
        Intro I = new Intro();
        I.BuatUI();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(I.GridIntro);

    }
```

But when i add dispatcher timer.
My silverlight program not work. only out a loading and never come the main program

```
private DispatcherTimer generalTimer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
        Intro I = new Intro();
        I.MakeUI();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(I.GridIntro);
        generalTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        generalTimer.Start();
        generalTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs a)
            {
                LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(I.GridIntro);
                IsiIdentitas();
                generalTimer.Stop();
            });
    }
```

In my visual studio the private DispatcherTimer generalTimer have green line it said the generalTimer never used.

please help me solve my problem

Comment: When you said "phenomenal", I was expecting something like a lottery win/super-powers/immortality. In comparison, your situation is somewhat run-of-the-mill!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never assigning a value to `generalTimer`, so it will still be `null` when you try to use it. Try this:

```
generalTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
```

just before you start assigning values to the properties (or at the point of declaration).